# Como manipular botões em tempo de execução no android

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Estou criando um app para um restaurante, onde eu já consigo listar os pedidos e criar a interface, exemplo:
coca-cola - 0 +
eu uso um for para percorrer um *List*, o que gera a lista de produtos.
MEU PROBLEMA:
Como esses elementos são criados em tempo de execução, não achei forma de manipula-los, eu preciso que quando o botão *+* for clicado uma função seja disparada incrementando o numero entre os botões, para isso a função deve pegar o valor entre os botões e incrementar mais *1*.
Para mesmo efeito, algo semelhante ao clicar no botão menos.

Fiz varias buscas no *google* e não achei nada sobre isso, eu consigo fazer essas funcionalidades usando de ***Js***.
Esse código está sendo executado dentro de um *fragment*, o *List* vem de uma interação com a *activity* que faz uma consumo de um *WEB service* via *JSON*.

```
for(int j=0;j<contador;j++)
        {

            LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(getContext());
            ll.setTag("ll"+j);
            ll.setLayoutParams(params);
            ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);


            TextView product = new TextView(getContext());
            product.setTextSize(15);
            product.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(520, 80));//LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT)
            product.setTop(0);
            product.setText(String.valueOf(prods.get(j).getNome()));
            ll.addView(product);

            /*
            TextView price = new TextView(getContext());
            price.setText(String.valueOf(prods.get(j).getCod()));
            ll.addView(price);*/

            Drawable me = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.skinbtnmenos);

            Button btn = new Button(getContext());

            btn.setId(j+1);
            btn.setTop(0);
            btn.setBackground(me);

            //btn.setText("Add");
            // set the layoutParams on the button
            btn.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(50, 50));


            TextView qtd = new TextView(getContext());
            qtd.setId(j);
            qtd.setTextSize(15);
            qtd.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(30, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));//LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT)
            qtd.setTop(0);
            qtd.setText("0");


            Drawable ma =getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.skinbtnmais);
            Button b = new Button(getContext());
            // Give button an ID
            b.setId(-j);
            b.setTop(0);
            b.setBackground(ma);
            // set the layoutParams on the button
            b.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(50, 50));

            final int index = j;
            // Set click listener for button
            btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (mListener!=null){
                        String id = v.getId()+"";
                        mListener.alterarValor(id);
                    }
                    /*Log.i("TAG", "index :" + index);*/
                    alerta("Valor:" + index);
                    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    //"Clicked Button Index :" + index,
                    //Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
            });

            //Add button to LinearLayout
            ll.addView(btn);
            ll.addView(qtd);
            ll.addView(b);

            //Add button to LinearLayout defined in XML
            parent.addView(ll);
        }
```

Comment: Pq tu não usa `RecyclerView` ? daí cria o layout, coloca tua lista na `adapter`, quando o usuario interagir tu altera a variavel do modelo que guarda a quantiade e depois dá um `notifyItemChanged(position)`

Comment: Veja `RecyclerView`, como @EduardoDornel citou. Dentro do `ViewHolder` do `RecyclerView` você implementa a lógica de incremento e decremento do produto e manda para o `Fragment` via [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) ou [Padrão Communicator](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/373419/nullpointerexception-ao-tentar-usar-interface-para-pegar-dados-de-uma-fragment-p/373454#373454)

Comment: Eu andei pesquisado sobre `RecyclerView`, mas ao menos nos tutorias que eu vi ela é instanciada no `onCreate`, passando a lista logo na montagem, o que não é meu caso.

Comment: No meu caso inicialmente é inflado um fragmento apenas com `EditText` e um `Button`, o qual o usuário digita o nome de um produto, o app envia uma requisição ao servidor o qual retorna um **JSON** com os produtos correspondentes, com isso eu gero o `List`, e processo eles no `Fragment`.

Comment: Eu consigo fazer o `RecyclerView` ser carregado depois da tela já ter sido montada?(Uma observação, sou novo em desenvolvimento para android, conheço apenas o básico de Java, más percebi que é bem diferente do desktop e do Web)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Boa! Estou desenvolvendo um App de PDV onde certos botões são criados em tempo de execução. 
Faço tudo entre o fragment e o adapter. Mas, o layout básico é um cardview que serão meu botão, esse cardview é controlado por um recicle. Neste em específico, também utilizo um swipper.

Abaixo seguem os códigos:

fragment_product.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorLightGray"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="140dp"
        android:background="@drawable/customborder"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="parent">

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/productViewItens"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
        android:background="@color/colorWhite"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingStart="5dp"
        android:paddingEnd="5dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:layout_weight=".50"
                android:gravity="start"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:text="TOTAL" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textProdTotal"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:layout_weight=".50"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:gravity="end"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:text="R$ 0,00" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:layout_weight=".50"
                android:gravity="start"
                android:text="Subtotal" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textProdSubTotal"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:layout_weight=".50"
                android:gravity="end"
                android:text="R$ 0,00" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:layout_weight=".50"
                android:gravity="start"
                android:text="Desconto" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textProdDes"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:layout_weight=".50"
                android:gravity="end"
                android:text="R$ 0,00" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:layout_weight=".50"
                android:gravity="start"
                android:text="Acréscimo" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textProdAcr"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:layout_weight=".50"
                android:gravity="end"
                android:text="R$ 0,00" />

        </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

product_grid_itens.xml (esse será o layout dos botões que serão criados em tempo de execução)

```
    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/cardViewProduct"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/button_primary_height"
    card_view:cardElevation="1dp"
    card_view:cardMaxElevation="1dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
    android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@color/colorWhite">

    <com.chauthai.swipereveallayout.SwipeRevealLayout
        android:id="@+id/prodItemSwipe"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        card_view:mode="same_level"
        card_view:dragEdge="right">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/prodSwipedelete_layout"
            android:layout_width="110dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:background="@color/colorLightGray">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/prodSwipeDeleteImg"
                    android:layout_width="24dp"
                    android:layout_height="24dp"
                    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:tint="@color/colorDarkGray"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_delete_white_24dp" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/btnEditProd"
                    android:layout_width="24dp"
                    android:layout_height="24dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
                    android:tint="@color/colorDarkGray"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_mode_edit_white_18dp" />
            </LinearLayout>

        </FrameLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/front_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textProdDesc"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:textColor="@color/colorDarkGray"
                android:layout_gravity="center|top"
                android:paddingTop="2dp"
                android:textSize="@dimen/title_size"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"

                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="18dp"
                    android:layout_height="18dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="left"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:tint="@color/colorDarkGray"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_monetization_on_white_18dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textProdPrice"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="18dp"
                    android:layout_weight=".25"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorDarkGray"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/title_size" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textProdDescAcr"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="18dp"
                    android:layout_weight=".25"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorDarkGray"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="right"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/title_size" />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="20dp"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    >
                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="18dp"
                        android:layout_height="18dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="left"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                        android:tint="@color/colorDarkGray"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_local_offer_white_18dp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textProdQtd"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="18dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorDarkGray"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:gravity="left"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/title_size" />

                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

        </FrameLayout>


    </com.chauthai.swipereveallayout.SwipeRevealLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

ProductFragment.java (O Fragmento dos produtos)

```
    package br.com.mbd.pdvx.Fragments;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import java.util.Objects;

import br.com.mbd.pdvx.Adapter.ProductItemAdapter;
import br.com.mbd.pdvx.AppFunctions;
import br.com.mbd.pdvx.R;

public class ProductFragment extends Fragment {

    private Context mContext;
    private Fragment mActivity;
    private static RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private static RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;
    private static RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;
    public static Fragment RefreshSalesFragment;
    public static View rootView;

    public static TextView textProdTotal;
    public static TextView textProdSubTotal;
    public static TextView textProdDes;
    public static TextView textProdAcr;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container,
                             @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_product, container, false);
        mContext = Objects.requireNonNull(getContext()).getApplicationContext();
        mActivity = ProductFragment.this;
        RefreshSalesFragment = this;

        try{
            mRecyclerView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.productViewItens);
            RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(rootView.getContext(), 1);
            mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

            mAdapter = new ProductItemAdapter(rootView.getContext(), AppFunctions.selectedListObj);
            mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        } catch (Exception e){
            Log.e("fragmentProduct error","error ->" + e.getMessage());
        }

        textProdTotal = rootView.findViewById(R.id.textProdTotal);
        textProdSubTotal = rootView.findViewById(R.id.textProdSubTotal);
        textProdDes = rootView.findViewById(R.id.textProdDes);
        textProdAcr = rootView.findViewById(R.id.textProdAcr);

        textProdTotal.setText(String.format("%.3f", AppFunctions.TOTAL_SALES));
        textProdSubTotal.setText(String.format("%.3f", (AppFunctions.TOTAL_SALES + AppFunctions.TOTAL_DESC - AppFunctions.TOTAL_ACRS)));
        textProdDes.setText(String.format("%.3f", AppFunctions.TOTAL_DESC));
        textProdAcr.setText(String.format("%.3f", AppFunctions.TOTAL_ACRS));

        return rootView;
    }

    public static ProductFragment newInstance(){
        return new ProductFragment() ;
    }

    public void refreshFragment() {

        Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity()).getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().detach(this).commitNow(); //commitAllowingStateLoss();
        getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().attach(this).commitNow();//commitAllowingStateLoss();

    }

}
```

ProductItemAdapter.java ( O Adapter que será o responsável por criar os botões, conectado com o xml do recicleview.

```
    package br.com.mbd.pdvx.Adapter;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.cardview.widget.CardView;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransaction;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.chauthai.swipereveallayout.SwipeRevealLayout;
import com.chauthai.swipereveallayout.ViewBinderHelper;

import java.util.List;

import br.com.mbd.pdvx.AppFunctions;
import br.com.mbd.pdvx.Fragments.Dialogs.ProductEditFragment;
import br.com.mbd.pdvx.Fragments.ProductFragment;
import br.com.mbd.pdvx.R;

public class ProductItemAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ProductItemAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private final ViewBinderHelper viewBinderHelper = new ViewBinderHelper();

    private static Context mContext;
    private static List<Object[]> mDataSet;
    static RecyclerView mRecyclerView;

    private static View front_layout;
    private static View prodSwipedelete_layout;
    private static ImageView prodSwipeDeleteImg;
    private static ImageView btnEditProd;

    public ProductItemAdapter(Context context,  List<Object[]> list){
        mContext = context;
        mDataSet = list;
    }

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        public CardView mCardView;
        public SwipeRevealLayout prodItemSwipe;
        public TextView textProdDesc;
        public TextView textProdPrice;
        public TextView textProdDescAcr;
        public TextView textProdQtd;

        public ViewHolder(View v){
            super(v);

            mCardView = v.findViewById(R.id.cardViewProduct);
            mRecyclerView = v.findViewById(R.id.viewSelected);
            prodItemSwipe = v.findViewById(R.id.prodItemSwipe);
            prodSwipedelete_layout = v.findViewById(R.id.prodSwipedelete_layout);
            prodSwipeDeleteImg = v.findViewById(R.id.prodSwipeDeleteImg);
            btnEditProd = v.findViewById(R.id.btnEditProd);

            front_layout = v.findViewById(R.id.front_layout);
            textProdDesc  = v.findViewById(R.id.textProdDesc);
            textProdPrice = v.findViewById(R.id.textProdPrice);
            textProdDescAcr  = v.findViewById(R.id.textProdDescAcr);
            textProdQtd = v.findViewById(R.id.textProdQtd);

        }

    }

    /** Após pegar o retorno é chamada a função para calcular os totais da venda
     * Antes de atribuir o valor do d/a é verificado se já existe um d/a
     * Caso exista, ele é retirado dos totais.
     * **/
    public static void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        if (resultCode != 0) {

            for (int x = 0; x< AppFunctions.selectedListObj.size(); x++){
                Object ab[] = AppFunctions.selectedListObj.get(x);

               // if (prodIdOffline.equals(ab[3])) {
                    String pv = (String) ab[1];
                    String qt = (String) ab[4];
                    String da = (String) ab[5];

                    if ((da != null) && (Double.parseDouble(da) != 0)){
                        AppFunctions.CalcTotal(Double.parseDouble(pv),Double.parseDouble(qt),Double.parseDouble(da),"DA-");
                    }

                    ab[5] = Double.toString(AppFunctions.DESC_ACR);
                    da = (String) ab[5];

                    if (da == null)
                        da = "0";

                    AppFunctions.CalcTotal(Double.parseDouble(pv),Double.parseDouble(qt),Double.parseDouble(da),"DA");
              //  }
            }
            ProductFragment PF = (ProductFragment) ProductFragment.RefreshSalesFragment;
            PF.refreshFragment();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public ProductItemAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType){
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.product_grid_itens,parent,false);
        ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v);

        return vh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position){

        try {

            Object selectedObj[] = mDataSet.get(position);

            String prodDesc = (String) selectedObj[0];
            String prodPrice = (String) selectedObj[1];
            final String prodidOffline = (String) selectedObj[3];

            String prodQtd = (String) selectedObj[4];
            String prodDescAcr = (String) selectedObj[5];

            double vQtd = Double.valueOf(prodQtd);
            double vDescAcr = 0;

            if (prodDescAcr != null)
                vDescAcr = Double.valueOf(prodDescAcr);

            holder.textProdDesc.setText(prodDesc);
            holder.textProdPrice.setText(prodPrice);
            holder.textProdQtd.setText(String.format("%.3f", vQtd));

            if (vDescAcr < 0){
                holder.textProdDescAcr.setTextColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorRed));
                holder.textProdDescAcr.setText(String.format("%.3f", vDescAcr));
            } else if (vDescAcr > 0){
                holder.textProdDescAcr.setTextColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorGreen));
                holder.textProdDescAcr.setText(String.format("%.3f", vDescAcr));
            }

            holder.mCardView.setTag(prodidOffline);

            prodSwipedelete_layout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                  //  mDataSet.remove(holder.getAdapterPosition());
                }
            });

            front_layout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    String displayText = "" + prodidOffline + " clicked";
                    Log.e("RecyclerAdapter", displayText);
                }
            });


            btnEditProd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    try {

                        FragmentTransaction ft = ((FragmentActivity)view.getContext()).getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                        ProductEditFragment productEditFragment= new ProductEditFragment();
                        productEditFragment.show(ft, "dialog");

                    } catch (Exception e){
                        Log.e("ProductEditFragment error","error -> "+e.getMessage());
                    }
                }
            });

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(" Erro ",e.getMessage());
        }

    }

    public void saveStates(Bundle outState) {
        viewBinderHelper.saveStates(outState);
    }
    public void restoreStates(Bundle inState) {
        viewBinderHelper.restoreStates(inState);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount(){
        return mDataSet.size();
    }

}
```

Veja o onclicklistener do front_layout, ele sempre irá passar o idoffline do botão que eu cliquei, e como esta é a tag que do botão (no caso um cardview), e é o mesmo id do produto, eu posso fazer o que for necessário, editar preço, quantidade etc.

Em outras palavras, o melhor approach é mesmo utilizando um recicle

Comment: Achei interessante seu exemplo, me ajudou a criar o `RecyclerView`, só não estou conseguindo chamar ele no meu fragmento, a unica diferença do seu basicamente, é que não vou chamar ele no `onCreateView`, pois nesse momento ainda não terei a lista de objetos, meu usuário vai pesquisar em uma barra de pesquisa no `Fragment` e so ai então terei a lista com os objetos, como implemento o `RecyclerView` nesse caso?

Comment: Boa! você pode criá-lo no oncreacteview vazio. E depois popula-lo no momento necessário, no seu caso, na pesquisa.  Eu uso este método para criar um recyclerView vazia e vou populando de acordo com seleções do usuário.

Comment: Fiz de uma forma que deu certo, mas ele da esse erro `E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout`, embora esse erro não feche a aplicação, queria solucionar

Comment: Da uma olhada na linha onde você atribui a view ao recyclerview e ao layoutmanager. Verifica se esta dando um findview na view correta. Ou então lá no adapter,lá no viewholder , verifica se o findview também está correto.